# How to update field values in a document - Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called `objects` / documents of type `Object` that has an an array of type `ObjectNotification`, I am trying to update each `notification.read` to `true`.

I have a view that displays all the `userNotifications` from all objects in a single array `self.viewModel.userNotifications`.

When `onAppear` for the view I am trying to set each `userNotification.read` to `true` in `self.viewModel.userNotifications` and update the FirestoreDB.

However I am not sure the best approach to take, currently I am looping through the arrays and trying to update each userNotification in `self.viewModel.objects.userNotifications` then update the document in the DB, which will update  `self.viewModel.userNotifications` as that fetches all `self.viewModel.userNotifications`.

But I get the following error as I am trying to change a struct, I was trying to change the value in my `for in` statement then called my `updateObect(object)` method to update the document in the DB.

> Cannot assign through subscript: 'h' is a 'let' constant

```
.onAppear() {
        // Mark as read
        let read = objectManager.markNotificationsAsRead(self.viewModel.userNotifications)
        self.viewModel.updateObjectNotifications(readNotifcations: read)
    }


func markNotificationsAsRead(_ notifications: [ObjectNotification]) -> [ObjectNotification]{
    
    // Mark notifications as read
    
    var readNotifications: [ObjectNotification] = []
    
    for n in notifications {
        if n.read == false {
            // Create new with true
            var new = n
            new.read = true
            readNotifications.append(new)
        }
    }
    
    // Return update notifications with read = true
    return readNotifications
}



func updateObjectNotifications(readNotifcations: [ObjectNotification]) {
    if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        for h in self.objects {
            for n in h.notifications {
                if n.deliveredTo == currentUser.email {
                    for r in readNotifcations {
                        if r.id == n.id {
                            // same notif for home
                            // h.notifications.rem
                             if let index = h.notifications.firstIndex(of: n) {
                                
                                h.notifications[index] = r // Cannot assign through subscript: 'h' is a 'let' constant
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                // update object in db
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of the approach above, how can I change the fields in the database ?

Comment: Please add more code to make this a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This question is super vague and incomplete. For example. You're asking about this line `for h in self.objects {` but we have no idea what `self.objects` is. We also don't know what any of your Classes or Structs look like - the error is pretty clear though, if the property `.notifications` of your `h` object (whatever that is) is let property it cannot be changed. Can you clarify what you're actually attempting to do (with Firebase) and add more info about what your models look like?

Answer (score 0):

This is is a solution to the actual problem and does not address the Firebase part of the question as that was not outlined in the actual question.

I'm going to take a wild guess here as the question is incomplete but I think whatever object 'h' is in the question is a struct which contains an array property of notifications.

If so, then you can't do this within a for loop

```
h.notifications[index] = r
```

because Structs are *value* types, unlike classes that are *reference* types. That means within the for loop, the objects are a *copy* of the array element, not the element itself

```
for copyOfArrayElement in someArrayOfStructs {}
```

There are a few solutions; here's two. The first is to iterate over the array using an index to access the actual struct object. Suppose we have an array of fruit structs with a name and an array property

```
struct FruitStruct {
    var name = ""
    var someList = [String]()
}

var banana = FruitStruct(name: "banana", someList: ["a", "b", "c"])
var grape = FruitStruct(name: "grape", someList: ["d", "e", "f"])

var fruitsArray = [banana, grape]
```

then the loop to modify every fruit name to be 'Hello' and element with index of 1  within the someList to be 'World'

```
for i in 0..<fruitsArray.count {
    fruitsArray[i].name = "Hello"
    fruitsArray[i].someList[1] = "World"
}

fruitsArray.forEach { print($0.name, $0.someList) }
```

and the output

```
Hello ["a", "World", "c"]
Hello ["c", "World", "e"]
```

Alternately change the struct to a class (which is a reference) so you can then modify the properties directly using your existing loop.

```
class FruitClass {
    var name = ""
    var someList = [String]()
    
    convenience init(withName: String, andArray: [String] ) {
        self.init()
        self.name = withName
        self.someList = andArray
    }
}
```